# Work on two different themes at the same time in wordpress

Tags: mobile

I have a website where I am using the Responsive theme for desktops and "Mobilize" theme for mobile devices. I am using the Any theme Switcher plugin to switch between the themes depending on the device from whic the site is accessed. 
The wordpress admin panel does not allow to modify a theme that is not currently active. Is there any way/plugin which will allow me to work on both the themes at the same time from the WP admin panel?

Many thanks,
Sarah

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ToolBar Theme Switcher](http://wordpress.org/plugins/toolbar-theme-switcher/). It will change the theme only for you while you are logged in. You can switch anytime using the Toolbar.